# Setting Flask session context within socket-io thread

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

I am having trouble with getting the right application/request context within flask-socketio. The end goal is to save USB connection data to a server-side session. This would allow me to setup a persistent view/get USB data from any page, and have the connection status stay the same when navigating to different pages. For now I am testing the session and trying to save anything in the right context (*testVar* below).

I have a flask-socketio background thread running every second. I assume passing current_app gives the right context to the thread. I have an application factory pattern for creating the application object. However, this makes it so I can't access the app object directly.

```
@socketio.event
def connect():
    global data_stream_thread
    with ds_thread_lock:
        if data_stream_thread is None:
            data_stream_thread = socketio.start_background_task(data_stream, current_app._get_current_object())
```

I'm passing the application context through to this background thread to save to the same session context:

```
def data_stream(app):
    while True:
        socketio.sleep(1)
        get_usb_connections(app)


def get_usb_connections(app):

    with app.test_request_context():
        session['testVar'] = 'test';

    # Code setting up variables for socketio emit

    socketio.emit(usb_response, {'data': data, 'device': device, 'color' : color})
```

Initialization of app, socketio, and session:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'auth.login'
bootstrap = Bootstrap()
async_mode = None
data_stream_thread = None
ds_thread_lock = Lock()
socketio = SocketIO(manage_session=False)
mail = Mail()
sess = Session()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    login.init_app(app)
    bootstrap.init_app(app)
    socketio.init_app(app, async_mode = async_mode)
    mail.init_app(app)
    sess.init_app(app)

   #blueprints
```

Is there a way to set the session context within a socket-io background thread, save variables to that session, and access that session from a blueprint route (through importing flask session) ?

Comment: Looks like you have some misunderstandings on how sessions work. First of all, the session is attached to the request context, which does not exist in your background thread. You can't use a test request context, as that is not associated with a client. And even if you managed to find a way to bring your request context into the thread, saving the session requires sending a cookie back to the client, which is not something you can do in a background thread. So basically you may need to rethink this. Maybe use a database instead of the session.

Comment: Is there a way to save variable states across routes and users other than sessions with flask? I already have a local user database, so I don't know about using that database. These states should only exist while the server is running.

Comment: The session is the correct place to save information between routes. The problem is that you want to save information in a background thread, which does not preserve the context that exists when route functions run.